# Draw rounded rectangle using a shader in OpenGL

Tags: java, user-interface, opengl, glsl, minecraft

I'm attempting to load a shader for a rounded rectangle in Java (OpenGL). The shader loads successfully, but the rounded corners are not visible. I suspect that one possibility is that the shader is attempting to draw outside the desired area, and the round edges are present but not visible.

I tried to play with the input values but nothing changed

My Vertex Shader is:

```c
#version 120

void main() {
    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
}
```

My Fragment Shader is:

```c
#version 120

uniform float round;
uniform vec2 size;
uniform vec4 color;

float alpha(vec2 d, vec2 d1) {
    vec2 v = max(abs(d) - d1, 0.0);
    return length(v) - round;
}

void main() {
    vec2 centre = .5f * size;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color.rgb, color.a * (1.f - smoothstep(0.f, 1.5f, alpha((gl_TexCoord[0].st * size) - centre, centre - 1.f))));
}
```

The code for loading the shader and setting it up is here:

```java
package de.simpleclient.shaders.shaderLoader;

import com.mojang.blaze3d.platform.GlStateManager;
import com.mojang.blaze3d.shaders.Uniform;
import com.mojang.blaze3d.systems.RenderSystem;
import com.mojang.blaze3d.vertex.*;
import de.simpleclient.roundedStuff.test2.renderutil.util.misc.ColorHelper;
import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.GameRenderer;
import org.checkerframework.checker.units.qual.C;
import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;

import static com.mojang.blaze3d.systems.RenderSystem.glDeleteVertexArrays;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11C.GL_QUADS;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30.glGenVertexArrays;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30C.glBindVertexArray;

/**
 * @author tryyan
 * @version on 08.01.2024
 */
public class Shader2 {

    private int shaderProgramId;
    public void init() {
        RenderSystem.assertOnRenderThread();
        int vertexShaderId = loadShader("C:\\Users\\\\Documents\\LYX_Launcherlast\\simple_client\\src\\main\\resources\\assets\\renderutil\\shaders\\vertex.vert", GL20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        int fragmentShaderId = loadShader("C:\\Users\\\\Documents\\LYX_Launcherlast\\simple_client\\src\\main\\resources\\assets\\renderutil\\shaders\\rounded.frag", GL20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

        shaderProgramId = createShaderProgram(vertexShaderId, fragmentShaderId);

        //System.out.println("Vertex Shader Compilation Log: " + GL20.glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShaderId));
        //System.out.println("Fragment Shader Compilation Log: " + GL20.glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShaderId));
        //System.out.println("Shader Program Linking Log: " + GL20.glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgramId));

    }

    private static int loadShader(String path, int type) {
        RenderSystem.assertOnRenderThread();
        StringBuilder shaderCode = new StringBuilder();
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                shaderCode.append(line).append("\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int shaderId = GL20.glCreateShader(type);
        GL20.glShaderSource(shaderId, shaderCode);
        GL20.glCompileShader(shaderId);

        // Überprüfe den Kompilierungsstatus
        if (GL20.glGetShaderi(shaderId, GL20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL11.GL_FALSE) {
            System.err.println("Shader compilation failed: " + GL20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderId));
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        return shaderId;
    }

    private FloatBuffer floatValues;
    public void setUniforms(float round, float sizeX, float sizeY, Color color,float x,float y) {
        RenderSystem.assertOnRenderThread();
        float[] c1 = ColorHelper.getColorComps(color);

        int roundUniform = GL20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramId, "round");
        GL20.glUniform1f(roundUniform, 10);

        int sizeUniform = GL20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramId, "size");
        GL20.glUniform2f(sizeUniform, sizeX, sizeY);

        int colorUniform = GL20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramId, "color");
        GL20.glUniform4f(colorUniform,c1[0], c1[1], c1[2], c1[3]);



    }


    private int createShaderProgram(int vertexShaderId, int fragmentShaderId) {
        RenderSystem.assertOnRenderThread();
        int programId = GL20.glCreateProgram();
        GL20.glAttachShader(programId, vertexShaderId);
        GL20.glAttachShader(programId, fragmentShaderId);
        GL20.glLinkProgram(programId);

        // Überprüfe den Link-Status
        if (GL20.glGetProgrami(programId, GL20.GL_LINK_STATUS) == GL11.GL_FALSE) {
            System.err.println("Shader program linking failed: " + GL20.glGetProgramInfoLog(programId));
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        // Lösche die Shader-Objekte, da sie bereits im Programm verknüpft sind
        GL20.glDeleteShader(vertexShaderId);
        GL20.glDeleteShader(fragmentShaderId);

        return programId;
    }


    public void useShader(){
        RenderSystem.assertOnRenderThread();
        GlStateManager._glUseProgram(shaderProgramId);
    }





    public void draw(double x, double y, double width, double height) {
        RenderSystem.assertOnRenderThread();

        // Use the shader before rendering

        // Set up the projection matrix
        FloatBuffer matrixBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
        RenderSystem.getProjectionMatrix().get(matrixBuffer);

        int projectionMatrixUniform = GL20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramId, "projectionMatrix");
        GL20.glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionMatrixUniform, false, matrixBuffer);

        // Define vertices, colors, and UV coordinates using full screen coordinates
        float[] vertices = {
                -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   // Vertex 1
                -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   // Vertex 2
                0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   // Vertex 3
                0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f    // Vertex 4
        };

        float[] colors = {
                1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  // Red for Vertex 1
                0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  // Green for Vertex 2
                0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,  // Blue for Vertex 3
                1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f   // White for Vertex 4
        };

        float[] uvCoordinates = {
                0.0f, 0.0f,   // UV for Vertex 1
                0.0f, 1.0f,   // UV for Vertex 2
                1.0f, 1.0f,   // UV for Vertex 3
                1.0f, 0.0f    // UV for Vertex 4
        };

        // Define indices for two triangles forming a quad
        int[] indices = {0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0};

        // Create and bind vertex array object (VAO)
        int vaoId = GL30.glGenVertexArrays();
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(vaoId);

        // Create and bind vertex buffer object (VBO) for vertices
        int vboId = GL15.glGenBuffers();
        FloatBuffer verticesBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vertices.length);
        verticesBuffer.put(vertices).flip();
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
        GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesBuffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        // Create and bind vertex buffer object (VBO) for colors
        int colorVboId = GL15.glGenBuffers();
        FloatBuffer colorBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(colors.length);
        colorBuffer.put(colors).flip();
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorVboId);
        GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        // Create and bind vertex buffer object (VBO) for UV coordinates
        int uvVboId = GL15.glGenBuffers();
        FloatBuffer uvBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(uvCoordinates.length);
        uvBuffer.put(uvCoordinates).flip();
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvVboId);
        GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvBuffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        // Create and bind element buffer object (EBO) for indices
        int eboId = GL15.glGenBuffers();
        IntBuffer indicesBuffer = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(indices.length);
        indicesBuffer.put(indices).flip();
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, eboId);
        GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesBuffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        // Enable vertex attributes
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(2); // Enable UV coordinates

        // Draw the quad using glDrawElements
        GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        // Disable vertex attributes and unbind VAO
        GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
        GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);

        // Delete VAO, VBOs, and EBO
        GL30.glDeleteVertexArrays(vaoId);
        GL15.glDeleteBuffers(vboId);
        GL15.glDeleteBuffers(colorVboId);
        GL15.glDeleteBuffers(uvVboId);
        GL15.glDeleteBuffers(eboId);

        // Stop using the shader after rendering
        GlStateManager._glUseProgram(0);
    }

    public void cleanup() {
        GL20.glDeleteProgram(shaderProgramId);
    }
}
```

Here is the draw function:

```java
public static void drawRoundedRect(double x, double y, double width, double height, double radius, Color color) {
        
        shader2.init();
        shader2.useShader();
        shader2.setUniforms((float) (radius*2),(float)10,(float)10, Color.red, (float) x, (float) y);
    
        shader2.draw(x, y , width, height);

        shader2.cleanup();
   }
```